# Very weird CSS behavior regarding aligning items vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, flexbox

I am trying to vertically center all elements inside many `div`s in my page. I added the required code, but weirdly only the first `div` is affected although **all divs are identical in their styles**.

I found it confusingly weird. I noticed that the problem occurred only when the browser window was at full-width. Then with some trials, I found that `auto` in `col-xl-auto` is the reason because when I removed it, the problem disappeared.

What do you think is the reason of this?

Here is a code that simulates the problem:

```css
#s2 {
  background-color: #C4E077;
}

#s3 {
  background-color: #B0CFE6;
}

.section {
  height: 30em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.text-justify {
  text-align: justify;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}

.sh {
  font-family: "Changa", "El Messiri";
  line-height: 1.7em;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  word-spacing: 0.3em;
  margin-bottom: 0.8em;
}

.sp {
  font-family: Scheherazade;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.mmm {
  margin: 0.7em 1.5em;
}

.image {
  width: 20em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amiri|Aref+Ruqaa|Cairo|Changa|El+Messiri|Jomhuria|Katibeh|Lalezar|Lateef|Mirza|Rakkas|Scheherazade" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container-fluid section" id="s2">
  <div class="row justify-content-xl-center align-items-center justify-content-end">
    <div class="col-xl-auto text-right mmm">
      <div class="image"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/aa/e1/b3/aae1b3459e6f56fbb26a64550efc992b.png"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3 mmm" dir=auto>
      <h4 class="text-right sh">
        موقعك سيظهر بشكل مناسب على كل أنواع الأجهزة</h4>
      <p class="text-justify sp">موقعك سيظهر بشكل مناسب على كل أنواع الأجهزة, موقعك سيظهر بشكل مناسب على كل أنواع الأجهزة. موقعك سيظهر بشكل مناسب على كل أنواع الأجهزة,موقعك سيظهر بشكل مناسب على كل أنواع الأجهزة</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid section" id="s3">
  <div class="row justify-content-xl-center align-items-center justify-content-end">
    <div class="col-xl-auto text-right mmm">
      <div class="image"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/aa/e1/b3/aae1b3459e6f56fbb26a64550efc992b.png"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3 mmm" dir=auto>
      <h4 class="text-right sh">
        نستخدم تقنيات لجعل موقعك أسرع تحميلاً</h4>
      <p class="text-justify sp">
        نستخدم تقنيات لجعل موقعك أسرع تحميلاً نستخدم تقنيات لجعل موقعك أسرع تحميلاًنستخدم تقنيات لجعل موقعك أسرع تحميلاًنستخدم تقنيات لجعل موقعك أسرع تحميلاً نستخدم تقنيات لجعل موقعك أسرع تحميلاً نستخدم تقنيات لجعل موقعك أسرع تحميلاً
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: it looks vertically centered to me. What's the problem?

Comment: looks fine to me too ??

Comment: No. There is a small difference. It is noticeable. Look at this image http://imgur.com/a/qcn4R

Comment: Notice also that the browser window should be wide. The problem won't appear in the code snippet of StackOverflow

Comment: I think you're using urdu in text so it might be causing problem because of word-break. So try adding `word-break: break-word;` and check if it's the word length which is causing problem. use this property in your `sh` class.

Comment: because I've seen same problem in case of using chinese.

Comment: @Chirag You might mean `word-break: break-word;`. However, it didn't work. I think that if there is a way to right-align the columns to the right of each row, it would solve the problem.

Comment: Your problem is solved or it's still as it is.?

Comment: No. It is still unsolved. I noticed that when I replace the text of the first paragraph with the text of the second, they appear aligned as I want.

Comment: Actually when I run your code in my laptop it's alright. But as you're stating that it's because of large display so I just can't figure it out that where is actual problem.

Comment: I think that your laptop screen should be wider than `1200px` to notice the problem due to the use of `xl`.

Comment: My resolution is 1366*768 but still I'm not able to visulize your issue.

Comment: I think there are two main things about this behavior: the horizontal alignment of each row which is given by `justify-content-xl-center`, and the use of `auto`..

Comment: Try viewing it on CodePen here : https://codepen.io/ammar_/pen/bWddJV